# Hi, how to set a color for the input/textarea at the status :visited?

Tags: css, textarea

Please advise, if it is possible to keep the 'color' of the textarea after it was visited.
In my case it is set to be #fff white, turns green on hover(all fantastic), and on mouseout turns into default black.

I am wondering if it is possible to fix it.

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
color:#fff !important;
font-size: 18px;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
input::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
color:#fff !important;
font-size: 18px;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
input:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
color:#fff !important;
font-size: 18px;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
textarea:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
color:#fff !important;
font-size: 18px;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;

}
textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder
{
color:#fff !important;
font-size: 18px;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
textarea::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
color:#fff !important;
font-size: 18px;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 } 
.contact__form input:hover,
.contact__form textarea:hover{

 width: 80%;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
 color:  #32A999;}

.contact__form input:focus,
.contact__form textarea:focus,
.contact__form input:visited,
.contact__form textarea:visited{

 background-color: #fff;
 color: #32A999;}
```

Here is an example of my code: https://codepen.io/justinegor/pen/dyXbopp .

Answer (score 0):

On mouseout, it is returning to default because you haven't yet defined it's regular `color` value (when not *placeholder*, *focus* or *visited*).

```
input,
text-area {
  color: white;   /* choose any color */
}
```

Here's your [codepen](https://codepen.io/eddireeder/pen/jOrPjvX?editors=1100), with the colour remaining green even after mouseout.